# Bitbake (Yocto) git fetch URI authentication

Tags: git, authentication, fetch, bitbake, yocto

How do I make a bitbake recipe that clones a git repo with built in authentication (into the url)?

What is the format of the SRC_URI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

`SRC_URI = "git://<host>/path/to/<repo>.git;protocol=<protocol>;user=<user>:<password>;branch=<branch>`

protocol might for example be `https`

Answer (score 0):

Per [the Bitbake User Manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.0/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-fetching.html) the proper format is

"<type>://[user:[password]@]<location>/<path>;<params>"

So you for example something like

"git://myusername:12345@git.somehost.com/myrepo;branch=main"

NOTE: The '/' and ';' are special characters that can't be used in the password.